# Should I hash a user-entered password if I only use it once?

Tags: java, passwords, password-protection

I'm writing a Java program that just logs in to a website and does some irrelevant stuff. I anticipate people other than myself will use it. So, I have a dialog (in terminal) that asks the user for a password and then uses that password to log in. After that, I don't need the password.

I use the `readPassword()` method from java.io.console which stores the password in a `char[]`. When I am done with the password, I iterate through the array and set all the values to 0.

Is this enough? Should I be hashing the password? To be honest, I don't really understand the point of hashing the password. The only way my char array could be compromised is if an attacker has access to my program memory. But, if an attacker has access to my program memory, then even if I hash, wouldn't they be able to see the password when the user enters/when I convert it to a `String` to login with it?

Thank you for help! For reference, I am using the HTMLUnit library to do the login. Not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: If you input the password, use it locally and then clear it, there doesn't seem to be any reason to also make a hash for it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "locally"?

Comment: Locally as opposed to sending the password anywhere else.

Comment: I mean I send it to website to log in? I'm guessing you're referring to sending it to another machine?

Comment: If you have to send the password itself to log on, then there is still no use hashing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not hash the password if you just use and discard it.

Hashing is for longer term password storage, as is usually made clear in any description of the process:

Here's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification):

> Storing all user passwords as cleartext can result in a massive security breach if the password file is compromised. One way to reduce this danger is to only store the hash digest of each password.

Here's [NIST 800-63B](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf):

> [The Key Derivation Functions' (i.e. password hasher's)] purpose is to make each password guessing trial by an attacker
> who has obtained a password hash file expensive and therefore the cost of a guessing attack high
> or prohibitive.

Here's [Wired](https://www.wired.com/2016/06/hacker-lexicon-password-hashing/):

> When hackers compromise a company to access its collection of users’ passwords, what they find and steal isn’t stored in a form that’s readable by humans—at least if the company has even a pretense of security. Instead, the cache of passwords is often converted into a collection of cryptographic hashes [..] to prevent them from being misused.

Secondly, password hashing only applies if you are *verifying* passwords, i.e. when someone logs in to your program/service. It does not apply if you are taking password input used to authenticate with a different service. A program like a password manager does not hash stored passwords, even though it stores them long term, because it's the various remote services and not the password manager that verifies the passwords (however, it *does encrypt* passwords).

There is no purpose in hashing a password that you use to log in somewhere and then immediately discard.

However, do be aware that you should *not* convert the `char[]` into a String if at all possible. If you turn it into a String, you lose control over the lifetime of the character data. When/if the String is collected, there is no guarantee that the data is overwritten in memory, and it may outlast the entire JVM. Various high profile exploits like Heartbleed, Spectre and RowHammer can take advantage of passwords that stay in memory for longer than necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I have to use a string for one part. I use the setValueAttribute() function from htmlunit to set the password value field in the html form. Unfortunately, that function takes in a string. I don't really see a way around that